# Get Max Insert Dates in SQL with JOINS

Tags: sql, actian

I have a list of tables:

```
select tableList
from information_schema.tables
```

Each of these tables have an insert date. I want to get the max(insertdate) of each of these tables, and place the insert date right next to it, like:

```
Column1   Column2
table1    MaxInsertDateTable1
table2    MaxInsertDateTable2
table3    MaxInsertDateTable3
table4    MaxInsertDateTable4
```

Is there a way to do this? I am using an MPP database:

http://www.actian.com/products/big-data-analytics-platforms-with-hadoop/matrix-mpp-analytics-databases/

Answer (score 0):

I would envision a query such as:

```
select 'table1' as column1, max(insertdate) as column2 from table1 union all
select 'table2' as column1, max(insertdate) as column2 from table2 union all
select 'table3' as column1, max(insertdate) as column2 from table3 union all
select 'table4' as column1, max(insertdate) as column2 from table4;
```